# NextJS fetch() throws invalid URL error when running next build but next dev works fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am making a NextJS React application and trying to fetch data from my server using this line:

```
let data = await fetch('/api/getAllAlumniInfoList').then(res => res.json())
```

When I run the server using `next dev`, everything works fine. But when I try to build the application for production using `next build` I get this error:

```
(node:173544) ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5491
            throw new TypeError("Failed to parse URL from " + input, { cause: err });
                  ^

TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/getAllAlumniInfoList
    at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5491:19)
    at Agent.fetch2 (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6288:25)
    ... 4 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at Wc (/app/goatconnect/goatconnect/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/app/goatconnect/goatconnect/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/app/goatconnect/goatconnect/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at Zc (/app/goatconnect/goatconnect/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:481) {
  [cause]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
      at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:564:9)
      at new URL (node:internal/url:644:5)
      at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5489:25)
      at Agent.fetch2 (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6288:25)
      at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7125:20)
      at fetch (node:internal/process/pre_execution:214:25)
      at onSearch (/app/goatconnect/goatconnect/.next/server/pages/coach/alumniView.js:75:30)
      at PlayersView (/app/goatconnect/goatconnect/.next/server/pages/coach/alumniView.js:103:9)
      at Wc (/app/goatconnect/goatconnect/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44) {
    input: '/api/getAllAlumniInfoList',
    code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'
  }
}
```

Another strange thing about this error is I have different pages with the same exact structure using the same logic that work fine and the compiler does not complain about. I am not sure what could be causing this API route to not be recognized correctly.

I have tried to use the NextJS provided hook `useSWR` which works in a lot of other instances but this specific use case is for a database search so using a hook causes a infinite loop when the page is updated with the results of the API call.

Comment: Are you sure that it's a valid url `/api/getAllAlumniInfoList`?

Comment: @Konrad yes, the fetch works fine when I run the application using `next dev`. The client can request data from the server at that route.

Comment: Can you please show how do you use other `fetch`s that don't throw an error?

Comment: @Konrad Sure, here is one example: `let data = await fetch('/api/getAllPlayerInfoList').then(res => res.json())`. It is a different route, but the page that it is on is doing the exact same logic for the "player list" rather than the "alumni list" where I am getting the error.

Comment: Are you calling the endpoint on the client-side in all cases? Also, have you tried deleting the `.next` folder?

Comment: You can use fetch, but you will have more code to do for a good implementation. useSWR has lots of benefits already implemented like caching, performance and other. I will try and make a real example of your use case.

Comment: @ivanatias you url shouldn't be in camelCase.

Answer (score 1):

### Why does the error happen  ?

The `fetch` api used by Next.js is ambiguous and depends on the context where it is executed :

- in the browser, it will refer to the fetch api from `window`
- on the server (and build phase), it will refer to the fetch api from `node`

As a consequence, you will need to disambiguate `fetch`.

If you do not want to disambiguate fetch, then you will have to use only valid `URL`s (in other words: no relative paths).

### How to disambiguate fetch

There are different ways to do it : use a library, use a [facade](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/facade) or make it explicit (see below).

Be aware that if you choose to make it explicit, you will have to separate client side code from server side code. If that still fits your needs, then :

- client side, use `window.fetch`
- server side, import node-fetch explicitly :

  ```
  import * as nodeFetch from "node-fetch";
  // use nodeFetch instead of fetch
  ```

**EDIT:** Node.js >= 21 includes fetch API natively (import `node:fetch` to use it).

### In a component

Using `componentDidMount`, the code will be executed only in the browser (implies that your data will be rendered client side).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the [URL constructor](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-validate-urls-in-javascript/).

```
const link = new URL(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/addviewer`);

  const res:any = await fetch(link, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(formData),
  });
```

Answer (score -2):

useSWR is a good option but for fetch i would recommend using unfecth as a fetcher for useSWR. Worked without issues for me.

```
import fetch from 'unfetch'
import useSWR from 'swr'

function YourComponent() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/getAllAlumniInfoList', fetch)

  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>
  return <div>hello {data.name}!</div>
}
```

An update with search input, useSWR and **no infinite loop**:

```
import { ChangeEvent, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import fetch from "unfetch";
import useSWR from "swr";
import { debounce } from "lodash";

const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

export default function Home() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");
  const { data = [], error } = useSWR(
    value ? `/api/user/${value}` : null,
    fetcher,
    {
      fallbackData: [],
    }
  );

  const onChange = debounce(
    useCallback(
      (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setValue(e.target.value),
      [value]
    ),
    500
  );

  if (error) {
    return <div>An error occured</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <input onChange={onChange} />
      {data?.map((e: any) => (
        <div key={Math.random()}>{e.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

IMPORTANT: value cannot be passed to input. Just pass onChange method.

On API side with fake data, filepath `/pages/api/user/[name].ts`:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

type Data = {
  name: string;
};

const data: Array<Data> = [
  { name: "John Doe" },
  { name: "Miss Pierce Bogisich" },
  { name: "Beaulah Tillman" },
  { name: "Aracely Hessel" },
  { name: "Margret Berge" },
  { name: "Hailee Macejkovic" },
  { name: "Lazaro Feeney" },
  { name: "Gennaro Rutherford" },
  { name: "Ian Hackett" },
  { name: "Sonny Larson" },
  { name: "Dr. Liza Wolf" },
];

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Array<Data>>
) {
  const {
    query: { name },
  } = req;
  console.log(name);
  res
    .status(200)
    .json(
      data.filter((e) =>
        e.name.toLowerCase().includes(`${name?.toString().toLowerCase()}`)
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: I have tried using useSWR and it works, but then I get an infinite loop because hooks re-run when the page reloads. This specific use case is for a search bar where the page will re load when the user types anything. So, the page reloads so useSWR runs which causes the page to reload and so on

Comment: in that case you should use a debounce, useEffect and callback.

Comment: Infinite loop is not happening because of useSWR but because of bad handling of your component or useEffect.